# LDAP + Workbench or LDAP + OG

Tags: workflows, authentication-authorization, taxonomy-terms

**I have come to an impasse in the development.**

**MY GOAL:** 
Setup department pages on the site, giving editing access to specific LDAP roles
Creating workflow for the data(draft,review,publish).
Creating private content for department users.

**My Solution(SO FAR):**

I have the LDAP module install on our D7 site.  I am mapping LDAP fields to the profiles and roles, Using LDAP queries with a view to display a "staff" page.

I have tinkered around with OG, Workbench, Workflow, TAC and TAC_lite. SO FAR NONE really meet the control and goals we have set out to obtain.

***I am hoping that there is someone out here that has conquered a similar setup and could impart some of their wisdom on me.***

***All constructive thoughts will be appreciated***

Answer (score 1):

Well after much trial and error  which included rebuilding permissions more times that I want to count. I came up with a solution based on the following link:

http://drupal.org/node/200631

A combination of Taxononmy Access Control and Taxonomy on content type, which allows for a almost module-less solution.

Hope this helps someone else.